# How to delete a foreign key of address from user table?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapping

My user is having one to one mapping with my address table, it has a foreign key of address in the user table. I want to delete the user address without deleting my user, but as I have the foreign key in the user table I am not able to do so, please help me out[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgQ8k.jpg%60@Entity)

@Table(name = "Address")
public class Address {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue 
private Integer addressId;

@NotNull(message="City should not be null")
@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z]+$" ,message="City should contain only alphabets")
private String city;

@NotNull(message="State should not be null")
@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z]+$" ,message="State should contain only alphabets")
private String state;

@NotNull(message="Pincode should not be null")
@Size(min=6,max=6,message = "Size must be of 6 elements")
@Pattern(regexp="\\d+", message = "Pincode must contain only numbers")
private String pinCode;

@NotNull(message="House number should not be null")
@Pattern(regexp="\\d+", message = "Pincode must contain only numbers")
private String houseNo;

@NotNull(message="Landmark should not be null")
private String landmark;
```

My User class

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "UserDetails")
public class User {
public enum Role{ADMIN,USER};``
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer userId;

```
@NotNull(message = "Firstname should not be null")
@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z '.-]*$", message = "Name should be alphabetic")
private String firstName;

@NotNull(message = "Firstname should not be null")
@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z '.-]*$", message = "Name should be alphabetic")
private String lastName;

@Email
private String email;

private String password;
private Role role;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<Order>();
private Address address;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<Order>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `orphanRemoval=true` just to be safe.

```java
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private Address address;
```

Then you should be able to delete the address by setting the value of the field to null such as:

```java
User user = userRepository.getById(1);
user.setAddress(null);
userRepository.save(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

PERSIST didn't work? If you want to have a look [here.](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types)

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Address address;
```

Answer (score 0):

What’s the error message you are getting? At database level, your foreign key “on delete set null” option needs to be set as well.

[Set null on delete](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete_null.php#:%7E:text=What%20is%20a%20foreign%20key,key%20fields%20set%20to%20NULL.)